# Timeout was reached - Authentication

Tags: raspbian

I disabled timeout in my Raspberry and when I run "xsqt q" command, the output will be:

```
prefer blanking: no
timeout: 0
DPMS is Disabled
```

But after several hours(8-9 hours) an error with another dialogbox will be displayed:

```
Timeout was reached
```

And I must login again.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: What timeout are you talking about and how did you disable it?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev There's a image to make it clear what timeout I'm talking about. I added xset s 0 0 xset s noblank xset dpms 0 0 0 to "autostart."

Comment: The dialog in your screenshot has no command name in it, and I genuinely have no idea where it comes from. I have seem similar dialogs from `xmessage` for instance. `xset` never produces any dialogs whatsoever.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thanks for your answer... But that's my problem. I don't know why it appears after several hours and where it does come from.

Comment: I have a Raspberry running 24/7 and I have never seen such a message popping out of nowhere. Do you get this on a vanilla Rapsbian too?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Okay, let's explain more about the scenario: I run a python code, it uses OMXPlayer to play some files in a loop. But I noticed OMXPlayer hangs after 7, 8 hours. So I changed the code... When the OMXPlayer freezed, it restarts the python program. Everything works fine, but between this restart process this timout error will be appear for 10seconds.
I don't know what a vanilla Raspbian is... If it helps, I use: Jessie 8.0 on Raspberry Zero.

Comment: A "vanilla" system means a system which was just installed and wasn't altered in any way. If you get an issue on a vanilla system, others can reproduce it as well, which means it's easier to find out the cause. I suppose that's not your case though.